# Anchor tags not closing in model service response after upgrade to hotfix 2.0.3

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, model-service

We are using SDL web 8.5 and DXA 2.0 Java . Recently we have applied Model service hotfix 2.0.3 and we have found that the model service response is missing closing tag for anchors. The anchor tags are a component link inside the rich text in CMS.
We have confirmed this issue by reverting back to the old version of Model service.

Comment: Is this the same issue as reported on GitHub? https://github.com/sdl/dxa-model-service/issues/11

Comment: @RickPannekoek this is a diffrent issue the link is resolving without a closing tag. suppose i added <a href="tcm3-7781" title="something">something</a> then i will see in model service response <a herf="/en/images/test.jpg" title="something"> something

Comment: Can you report a separate GitHub issue for this, then? Please also verify if the issue occurs in 2.0.2.

Comment: new issue opened for this. https://github.com/sdl/dxa-model-service/issues/12

Comment: Thanks. Can you confirm the issue occurs with 2.0.3, but not with 2.0.2?